# Access Denied Error while uploading images

Tags: asp.net, .net, file-upload, access-denied

While uploading image to the server i am getting access denied error by the server. Is there any work out for the same.

Here is the stacktrace as well as the screenshot[image]

> Server Error in '/' Application. Access to the path
>   'G:\PleskVhosts\rstechnopoint.com\fitness-first.rstechnopoint.com\images_1EP017.jpg'
>   is denied. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the
>   path
>   'G:\PleskVhosts\rstechnopoint.com\fitness-first.rstechnopoint.com\images_1EP017.jpg'
>   is denied.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File
>   Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add"
>   to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account,
>   and check the boxes for the desired access.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 113:                    path =
>   HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/"); Line 114:
>   path += "images/"+ vUpload; Line 115:
>   imageupload.SaveAs(path); Line 116: Line 117:
>   vPicture = "~/images/"+ imageupload.FileName.ToString();
>
> Source File:
>   g:\pleskvhosts\rstechnopoint.com\fitness-first.rstechnopoint.com\profile\editprofile.aspx.cs
>   Line: 115
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   'G:\PleskVhosts\rstechnopoint.com\fitness-first.rstechnopoint.com\images_1EP017.jpg'
>   is denied.]    System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath) +7724975    System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path,
>   FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights,
>   FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options,
>   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
>   +1162    System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions
>   options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) +61
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode) +55
>   System.Web.HttpPostedFile.SaveAs(String filename) +99
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload.SaveAs(String filename) +23
>   profile_editprofile.uploadbtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   g:\pleskvhosts\rstechnopoint.com\fitness-first.rstechnopoint.com\profile\editprofile.aspx.cs:115
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +110
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +36    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1565

Comment: I'm not an ASP coder but this seems like folder permission misconfiguration, make sure that the folder you are trying to upload to has the necessary permissions

Comment: do u use iis express or IIS

Comment: @odedta Seems to me the same problem, But here is the thing, I don't have any knowledge how to change the necessary permission. Do you have any idea?

Comment: In my experience Plesk panel is far less advanced than the PHP cPanel. As far as I know it does not allow you to change folder permissions on your own, your hosting company should have a tech help chat/email, you can send them a message.

Comment: There you go: http://imgur.com/Ccm0wn9
this is very basic though :/

Comment: Don't forge to upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience Plesk panel is far less advanced than the PHP cPanel. As far as I know it does not allow you to change folder permissions on your own, your hosting company should have a tech help chat/email, you can send them a message

There you go: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5VTq.jpg) is very basic though :/

Comment: i had similar issue in Go Daddy hosting, and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34288986/2218697) is the answer. hope helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

In plesk's current file manager GUI it is simple to change access permissions if you know where to look (it's easy to miss).  When you hover over a row a drop down icon will appear to the right, as shown below.

[image]

Give write permissions to the appropriate account and you should be good to go.